# How to avoid page being refreshed when using SetFocusOnError="true"

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a required field validator where I added property for SetFocusOnError="true"

```
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidatorFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="message-validation-color"
                        Text="Required first name!"  
                        SetFocusOnError="true"
                        ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" />
                        <br/>
```

But whenever I click on the submit button. The focus will be set on the textbox for the first name (which is actually my target). BUT then the page reloads and the focus will be lost.
I noticed  that when I do not include the SetFocusOnError="true", page does not reload.

Do I need to add any validation when using SetFocusOnError="true"?

I just want the focus to be on the field where there is an error and NOT for the page to be reloaded.

Comment: do you have any javascript attached to onclick of your submit button? if yes then look into that either that is submitting your form or it have some error

Answer (score 0):

2 things to try:

1. Place an Update Panel around your form elements
2. ensure that all your form elements and Validators all use the same "ValidationGroup", including the button you're using to submit the form